# Event Not Counting Number of Characters in Tag

Tags: jquery, html, dom-events

I'm having issues where my JavaScript code is not counting the characters that is being input and I'm at a lost.  Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajaxgoogleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="studentName">Student name:</label>
<textarea id="studentName" cols="40" rows"3"></textarea><br>
<p id="stringLength">0</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var $textareaElement = $("#studentName");

function textSize(event) {
   $("#stringLength").text($textareaElement.val().length);
}

/* Your solution goes here */
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#studentName").focus(function () {

$("#stringLength").html($(this).val().length);

});

});
```

Test:

Testing the number of characters in "Hi" is shown
Yours and expected differ. See highlights below.

> Yours
>   0
>   Expected
>   2

Testing the number of characters in "How are you?" is shown
Yours and expected differ. See highlights below.

> Yours
>   0
>   Expected
>   12

Testing the number of characters in "Good Game" is shown
Yours and expected differ. See highlights below.

> Yours
>   0
>   Expected
>   9

Comment: Where exactly is `textSize` being used in the logic?

Comment: @Taplar wouldn't it be called while utilizing the function for the script?

Comment: Where is it utilized?  You create the method and it's never used.

Answer (score 0):

[focus](https://api.jquery.com/focus/#focus-handler) will fire when the element gains focus.  [keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/#keyup-handler) is what you're looking for if you want to count characters as user types them into the input.